# Snackbar styles - Angular Material 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-5

I'm using Angular 6 and Material 6 and I need to set **margin-bottom: 20px** to a snackbar. The problem I have is that the animations overlap when one is closed and the other is opened. How can I solve that?

1) Correct way (web example). When a new message has to be displayed, the snackbar disappears completely, before a new one appears
(https://scrud.herokuapp.com/book)
[image]

2) My code (bad)

[image]

**Example:** Go to oficial snackbar example (https://stackblitz.com/angular/qyllrqbvykv?file=styles.css). Go to "style.css" and add this piece of code and click many time on button.

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Please share your template code where you have added the snackbar

Comment: Try adding `paneClass` property of **snakebar**. "Extra CSS classes to be added to the snack bar container." and you can add margin in that class

Comment: @Faisal Hi and thx! go to updated question, Example section

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material produces the sliding effect by animating a translateY transform. I don't think there is any way to get around the overlap. What you could try is to deliberately call `dismiss()` first, then call `open()` in a `setTimeout()` using a short delay. The only problem with that is that the snackbar will always have that delay, unless you can find a way to avoid the delay if no snackbar is open. You might be able to use the `afterDismissed()` and `afterOpened()` observables to do that but it seems tricky.

Crude example:

```
openSnackBar(message: string, action: string) {
  this.snackBar.dismiss();
  setTimeout(() =>
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 2000,
    }), 500
  );
}
```